# MySQL : Get row of table on same column of three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, the first one is called "File" :

```
JobId    FilenameId    FileId
5        2             1  
7        3             2
```

And the second one is called "Filename"

```
Filename    FilenameId
File1         2    
File2         3
```

And the third one is called "Client" :

```
ClientId    JobId
1           5 
2           7
```

Now I want to get the ClientId of File1, how can I do it? I'm new to SQL.

Thanks.

Edit : this is what I tried but it's not working

```
Select c.ClientId 
From `File` f, Filename fn, Client c
Where f.FilenameId = fn.FilenameId and f.JobId = c.JobId and fn.Filename = "File1";
```

Comment: Learn about [**SQL Joins**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). You can use multiple joins in a query. Providing a straight answer will not do anything good in your career. Learn by yourself, improve your skills.

Comment: @RagingBull So you're saying this query is too broad?

Comment: @Strawberry: Don't you think it is better to show the way instead of giving the straight solution for such simple questions? FYI, I didn't vote to close the question.

Comment: @Raging Bull can you please have a look at what I've tried it's still not working

Comment: Maybe use ` to escape the table name File. \`File\`

Comment: @brest1007: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I hate the negative banter that sometimes goes on, but yes, you need to get yourself more educated in SQL during your learning.  Look here at real-life scenarios and how people offer different solutions to the same.

Now to YOUR question.  First, get rid of old style sql where you put all the join criteria in your where clause.  Get started knowing the proper relationships between the tables.  Second, your WHERE clause should be the basis of your specific criteria -- such as you want File 1.  From that, get to the other tables.  My personal standard of SQL coding shows first the what criteria do I want and from what table.  Ensure indexes are available for optimizing the query.  THEN join to the other tables to get the other elements needed to complete the row of data.  (Good use of table "aliases", and keep with it).

First, your main criteria.  Simple enough.

```
select
      fn.FileNameID,
      fn.FileName
   from
      FileName fn
   where
      fn.FileName = 'File1'
```

From there, do your joins to get the next pieces of information from file to client relationships

```
select
      fn.FileNameID,
      fn.FileName,
      c.clientID
   from
      FileName fn
         JOIN File f
            on fn.FileNameID = f.FileNameID
            JOIN Client c
               on f.JobID = c.JobID
   where
      fn.FileName = 'File1'
```

Notice the hierarchical indentation from file name to the file, then from file to the client... you can visually see how the tables are related.  Then, just grab your other columns as you need and add to your field list with proper aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select ClientId from Client where JobId in (select JobId from File where FilenameId in (select FilenameId from Filename where Filename="File1"));